# XSLT current-group select first and last element

Tags: html, xml, xslt, xpath

I have this xml:

```
    <LocatorInfo>
        <LocationAddr>
            <StreetNum>182</StreetNum>
            <StreetName>Eastern Avenue</StreetName>
            <City>Fall River</City>
            <StateProv>MA</StateProv>
            <PostalCode>02723</PostalCode>
            <Country>USA</Country>
            <GEOCode>
                <Latitude>41.694600119635915</Latitude>
                <Longitude>-71.13038416718094</Longitude>
            </GEOCode>
        </LocationAddr>
        <LocationTimestamp>4/6/2018 4:17:37 PM</LocationTimestamp>
        <LocationDistance>4.338 miles</LocationDistance>
        <Accuracy>1.985 miles</Accuracy>
    </LocatorInfo>
    <LocatorInfo>
    <LocationAddr>
      <StreetNum>285</StreetNum>
      <StreetName>Wastern Avenue</StreetName>
      <City>Ball River</City>
      <StateProv>MA</StateProv>
      <PostalCode>02723</PostalCode>
      <Country>USA</Country>
      <GEOCode>
        <Latitude>41.694600119635915</Latitude>
        <Longitude>-71.13038416718094</Longitude>
      </GEOCode>
    </LocationAddr>
    <LocationTimestamp>4/7/2018 7:00:03 AM</LocationTimestamp>
    <LocationDistance>4.338 miles</LocationDistance>
    <Accuracy>1.985 miles</Accuracy>
  </LocatorInfo>
<LocatorInfo>
        <LocationAddr>
            <StreetNum>182</StreetNum>
            <StreetName>Eastern Avenue</StreetName>
            <City>Fall River</City>
            <StateProv>MA</StateProv>
            <PostalCode>02723</PostalCode>
            <Country>USA</Country>
            <GEOCode>
                <Latitude>41.694600119635915</Latitude>
                <Longitude>-71.13038416718094</Longitude>
            </GEOCode>
        </LocationAddr>
        <LocationTimestamp>4/7/2018 4:17:37 PM</LocationTimestamp>
        <LocationDistance>4.338 miles</LocationDistance>
        <Accuracy>1.985 miles</Accuracy>
    </LocatorInfo>
```

I have this part of xslt:

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="n1:MBMDVRs/mbg:LocatorInfo" group-by="string-join((mbg:LocationAddr/mbg:StreetNum, mbg:LocationAddr/mbg:StreetName, mbg:LocationAddr/mbg:City, mbg:LocationAddr/mbg:StateProv), '!')">
                                                    <tr style="border-collapse:collapse; font-size:inherit; text-align:center; " class="wide">
                                                        <td style="width:0.95in; ">
                                                        </td> 
                                                        <td style="width:2.57in; "> 
                                                            <xsl:copy-of select="mbg:LocationAddr/mbg:StreetNum, mbg:LocationAddr/mbg:StreetName, mbg:LocationAddr/mbg:City, mbg:LocationAddr/mbg:StateProv" />
                                                        </td>
                                                        <td style="width:1.50in; "> 
                                                        <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
                                                            <xsl:copy-of select="(//mbg:LocationTimestamp)[last()]"/>
                                                            </xsl:for-each>
                                                        </td>
                                                        <td style="width:2.13in; ">
                                                        <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
                                                            <xsl:copy-of select="mbg:LocationTimestamp[1]"/>
                                                            </xsl:for-each>
                                                        </td>
                                                        <td style="width:2.27in; ">
                                                             <xsl:value-of select="count(current-group())" />
                                                        </td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                       </xsl:for-each-group>
```

I can't figure out why the last and [1] commands don't work in this case. They do nothing. I want to get the first Timestamp for each group in one td and last Timestamp in another td. But they get bundled together in both cells. It returns the same result either if I use [1] and last or not. Is it because the Timestamp is not in the group? How can I bypass this? Don't know if it's possible like this or if I have to try a completely different way.

The namespaces are used correctly, I just left them out of the xml.

Comment: If you group `LocatorInfo` elements with `for-each-group` and inside of it you want to select the first and last item in each group then you would use `.` or `current-group()[1]` for the first and `current-group()[last()]` for the last `LocatorInfo` in each group. To select the `LocationTimestamp` child of them would be `./LocationTimestamp` or `current-group()[1]/LocationTimestamp` and `current-group()[last()]/LocationTimestamp`.Any attempts shown with `//LocationTimestamp` in your code would not select `LocationTimestamp` of the items in a certain group but rather of the whole document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the required braces to the second expression like below. In your sample code the first and the last values are output twice due to the `xsl:for-each` (don't know what it's good for).

```
<td style="width:1.50in; "> 
    <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
        <xsl:copy-of select="(//mbg:LocationTimestamp)[last()]"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
</td>
<td style="width:2.13in; ">
    <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
        <xsl:copy-of select="(//mbg:LocationTimestamp)[1]"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
</td>
```

The output (partial) is:

```
<td style="width:1.50in; ">    <!-- last() -->
    <LocationTimestamp xmlns="mbg.com">4/7/2018 4:17:37 PM</LocationTimestamp>
    <LocationTimestamp xmlns="mbg.com">4/7/2018 4:17:37 PM</LocationTimestamp>
</td>
<td style="width:2.13in; ">   <!-- [1] -->
    <LocationTimestamp xmlns="mbg.com">4/6/2018 4:17:37 PM</LocationTimestamp>
    <LocationTimestamp xmlns="mbg.com">4/6/2018 4:17:37 PM</LocationTimestamp>
</td>
...
<td style="width:1.50in; ">    <!-- last() -->
    <LocationTimestamp xmlns="mbg.com">4/7/2018 4:17:37 PM</LocationTimestamp>
</td>
<td style="width:2.13in; ">    <!-- [1] -->
    <LocationTimestamp xmlns="mbg.com">4/6/2018 4:17:37 PM</LocationTimestamp>
</td>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. No idea why I thought the for-each loops where required. They weren't. I jsut removed them and it works great.